# Regex for comparing Strings with spaces

Tags: regex, string

Im trying to compare is a string is present among a list of Strings using regex.

I tried using the following...

```
(?!MyDisk1$|MyDisk2$)
```

But this isnt working... for the scenarios like

```
(?!My disk1$|My Disk2$)
```

Can you suggest a better approach to deal with such situations..

I get the list of strings from an sql query... So I am not sure where the spaces are present. The list of Strings vary like My Disk1, MyDisk2, My_Disk3, ABCD123, XYZ_123, MNP 123 etc.... or any other String with [a-zA-Z0-9_ ]

Comment: i have changed the answer.see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make the spaces optional using a zero-or-one quantifier (`?`):

```
(?!My ?disk1$|My ?Disk2$)
```

This assertion will reject substrings like `MyDisk2` or `My Disk2`. Or to handle potentially many spaces, use a zero-or-more quantifier (`*`):

```
(?!My *disk1$|My *Disk2$)
```

Note that if you're running this in an engine which ignores whitespace in the pattern you may need to use a character class, like this:

```
(?!My[ ]*disk1$|My[ ]*Disk2$)
```

Or to handle spaces or underscores:

```
(?!My[ _]*disk1$|My[ _]*Disk2$)
```

Unfortunately if the spaces can be anywhere in the string, (but you still care about matching the other letters in order), you'd have to do something like this:

```
(?! *M *y *d *i *s *k *1$| *M *y *D *i *s *k *2$)
```

Or to handle spaces or underscores:

```
(?![ _]*M[ _]*y[ _]*d[ _]*i[ _]*s[ _]*k[ _]*1$|[ _]*M[ _]*y[ _]*D[ _]*i[ _]*s[ _]*k[ _]*2$)
```

But to be honest, at that point, you may be better off preprocessing your data before you try to use your regex with it.

Comment: I have to deal with "MyDisk" and "My Disk" as separate strings.. And I get the list of Strings from a sql query.... So I wont be able to know where the spaces are present

Comment: I get a list of Strings... Strings can be like.. My Disk1, MyDisk2, My_Disk

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
/(?[^\s_-]+(\s|_|-)?[^\s_-]*?$)/i
```

'?' quantifier means 0 or 1 of the preceding pattern.
/i is for case insensitive. The separator can be space or underscore or dash.I have replace My and disk with a string of length 1 or more which does not contain space ,underscore or dash.. Now it wil match "Shikhar Subedi" "dprpradeep" or "MyDisk 54".

The + quantifier means 1 or more. ^ means not. * means 0 or more. So the string after the space is optional.

Comment: I get the list of Strings from a sql query.... So I wont be able to know where the spaces are present

Comment: But I wont be able to know where the spaces are... I get the list of Strings from an sql query. The strings may vary like 'Shikhar Subedi', 'dbpradeep123', 'tom_hanks', 'Disk 54' etc...

Comment: it is like a list of email names with spaces... I need to check if the new string is not present in that list

Answer (score 0):

use this `Regex` upending i at the end that will mean that your `regex` is case-insensitive

```
/my\s?disk[12]\$/i
```

this will match all possible scenarios.